# Why do buttons on mobile browsers appear to have a larger click area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

At work, they needed a quick and dirty example to hand-sign a document and append it to JSON as a base64 Data URL. It works all fine and dandy in itself, but my own curiosity got the better of me and I was annoyed to find out, that the area of the buttons appeared to be much larger on mobile than they looked like. But even inspecting buttons in my example project didn't help me a lot to pin down the problems.

**Disclaimer**: I have to also point out, for people who look for a similar solution to **NOT** just copy-paste this example here. It's serviceable and works probably in 99% of the cases just fine for this purpose, but the drawing is not optimal. Why? Because I keep adding points **indefinitely** as long as the finger touches the canvas... and with each move, it goes through the array and **REDRAWS** all the lines! It becomes pretty noticeable after you covered a fair portion of the small canvas. It would be more elegant to go through the tracked points and kick them out of the array once drawn and not only when we raise the finger from the touchscreen. But if you merely use it to sign something like in my example, the example should be perfectly serviceable with no frills.

[image]

[image]

I did add a snippet as well. Don't forget, it's only working on mobile browsers or if you use emulation on your chrome browser, for example.

```js
"use strict";

const canvas = document.getElementById('sign');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.lineJoin = 'round';
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.lineWidth = 2;

let points = [];
let isPainting = false;

setup();

function setup() {
    if (isMobile() || isIpad()) {
        setupMobile();
    } else {
        // Some other stuff that was supposed to happen, but was canned
        setupDesktop();
    }
}

function setupDesktop() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        addToDrawingPointsTouch(canvas, e);

        if (!isPainting) {
            isPainting = !isPainting;
        }

        const ctx = context;

        // Not the most elegant solution for the initial call, but touchmove takes a bit to trigger
        const initialStarting = points[0];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(initialStarting.x, initialStarting.y);
        ctx.lineTo(initialStarting.x, initialStarting.y);
        ctx.stroke();

    }, { passive: true })

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        if (isPainting) {
            addToDrawingPointsTouch(canvas, e);

            const ctx = context;

            points.forEach((v, index) => {

                if (points[index + 1]) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(v.x, v.y);
                    ctx.lineTo(points[index + 1]?.x, points[index + 1]?.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            })
        }
    }, { passive: true })

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        if (isPainting) {
            isPainting = !isPainting;
            points = [];
        }
    }, { passive: true })
}

function setupMobile() {
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
        addToDrawingPointsTouch(canvas, e);

        if (!isPainting) {
            isPainting = !isPainting;
        }

        const ctx = context;

        // Not the most elegant solution for the initial call, but touchmove takes a bit to trigger
        const initialStarting = points[0];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(initialStarting.x, initialStarting.y);
        ctx.lineTo(initialStarting.x, initialStarting.y);
        ctx.stroke();

    }, { passive: true })

    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
        if (isPainting) {
            addToDrawingPointsTouch(canvas, e);

            const ctx = context;

            points.forEach((v, index) => {

                if (points[index + 1]) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(v.x, v.y);
                    ctx.lineTo(points[index + 1]?.x, points[index + 1]?.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            })
        }
    }, { passive: true })

    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
        if (isPainting) {
            isPainting = !isPainting;
            points = [];
        }
    }, { passive: true })
}

function addToDrawingPointsTouch(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    const x = event.touches ? event.touches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
    const y = event.touches ? event.touches[0].clientY : event.clientY;

    points.push({
        x: (x - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
        y: (y - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
    });
}

function isMobile() {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function isIpad() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac/) && navigator.maxTouchPoints && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        false;
    }
}

function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function createCanvasPngDataUrl() {
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

```css
body {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: none;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script defer src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form">
        <canvas style="border: 1px solid black;" id="sign">
        </canvas>
    </form>

    <div id="menu">
        <button onclick="createCanvasPngDataUrl()">Create DataUrl</button>
        <button onclick="clearCanvas()" id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code snippet had no this problem

Comment: @PetePearl I feel this ruins my day. On all my devices this seems to be the case. I have to ask if that happens to my coworkers, really. I hate it when I don't KNOW things. Thanks for trying it out!

Comment: why your animation has empty place before buttons?

Comment: @PetePearl Funny thing, because the overlap of the buttons was SO massive, I was unable to start drawing a line around the lower section of the image. That's why I created an arbitrary gap.

Comment: can you make screenshot with selected button in chrome devtools?

I think your button has extrastyles

Comment: @PetePearl Just like my snippet, no additional styles. I uploaded the image